# Android studio cannot resolve mapActivity

Tags: android, extends, oncreate, mapactivity

I am trying to input source code from [codly.io](https://codly.io)
which enables me to convert PSD designs into java source.

However, once imported and after fixing issues with appcompact and google play service, I get an error saying it cannot resolve MapActivity.

or during the `super.onCreate` it cannot resolve the method.

```
public class Login extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_login);
    initView();
}

private void initView(){



    //TODO add extra view initialization code here
}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}


public void onLoginClicked(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DriverSelect.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onBpClicked(View v){
    this.finish();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it cannot resolve MapActivity

`MapActivity` is from the old, defunct MapsV1 way of integrating Google Maps. Since you cannot get API keys for MapsV1 anymore, you will need to modify your code to [use MapsV2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

This also does not speak well for that service, as to how much they are paying attention to their Android code generation, given that MapsV1 was deprecated 1.5 years ago.